# Exact sequence associated to a acyclic complex

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

I am reading chapter V of 'Homological Algebra' by Cartan and Eilenberg.

1. > Regarding a module $A$ as a complex with $A^0=A$, $A^n=0$ for $n\neq 0$ and zero differentiation. The augmentation $\epsilon$ of a left complex $X$ over $A$ to $A$ then reduces to $\epsilon : X_0\rightarrow A$ such that $X_1\rightarrow X_0\rightarrow A = 0$.
   >
   > $X$ is called acyclic if $\epsilon$ induces an isomorphism $H(X)\approx A$. This last condition is equivalent to the requirement that the sequence $...\rightarrow X_n \rightarrow X_{n-1} \rightarrow ...X_{-1} \rightarrow X_0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow 0$ be exact.

Why $X_{n-2}\rightarrow X_{n-1}\rightarrow X_n$ for any $n$ is exact? The definition of acyclic-ness depends only on $\epsilon$, which deals only with $X_1$, $X_0$, and $A$.

2. > (page 79) if the exact sequence $0\rightarrow X'' \rightarrow X \rightarrow X'\rightarrow 0$ splits, then $X\approx X'' + X'$

which theorem/proposition is used here?

Comment: 1. $\varepsilon$ is determined by $\varepsilon \colon X_0 \to A$ and that the composition is zero, but $\varepsilon$ is a chain map which is defined in all degrees, so it induces a morphism of all homology groups. 2. This is even a equivalence, so the converse is also true, but I don't have the book here.

Comment: 2. is called the [splitting lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma).

Comment: @user60589 thanks for your comment. By inducing morphisms of all homology groups, you mean morphisms $\epsilon^{*}: H^n(X) \rightarrow H^n(A)$, right? How does that help induce morphisms between submodules $X^n$ of $X$ themselves?

Comment: The morphisms are part of the data of $X$, since $X$ is a complex(or in other words a module with a collection of submodules with morphisms satisfiying …).

Comment: @user60589 yes I know about the definition of a complex, which does not include the exactness of the sequence $X_{n-2}\rightarrow X_{n-1}\rightarrow X_n$.

Comment: @user60589  It only requires Im$(X_{n-2}\rightarrow X_{n-1}) \subset$Ker$(X_{n-1}\rightarrow X_n)$

Comment: But $H^n(X)$ is zero if and only if  $X_{n-1}\rightarrow X_{n}\rightarrow X_{n+1}$ is exact.